# How to vertically center dialog box at the its current scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, center

How would I be able to vertically center the dialog box at its current scroll position of the window when either one of the "show dialog" buttons is clicked?

Example: When I click the bottom on locations 3. I'm trying to get the dialog box to be vertically centered at that current viewing window screen. And this should be the case for all buttons.

```js
$('.show-dialog-btn').click(function() {

  $('#dialog-box').addClass('display-dialog-box');
});



$('.close-dialog-btn').click(function() {

  $('#dialog-box').removeClass('display-dialog-box');
});
```

```css
.locations-container {
  padding: 10px
}

.locations-container:not(last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 100px
}

.locations-container:nth-child(3) {
  background: #eee
}

#dialog-box {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
  width: 220px;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
}

#dialog-box.display-dialog-box {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--- Locations 1 Div ---->
<div class="locations-container">
  <h2>Locations 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus aliquid quas, ut fugiat, ipsum, veniam aut fuga impedit sunt laboriosam praesentium ullam quisquam eos rem voluptas corporis vel hic natus!</p>

  <button class="show-dialog-btn">Show Dialog</button>
</div>


<!--- Locations 2 Div ---->
<div class="locations-container">
  <h2>Locations 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus aliquid quas, ut fugiat, ipsum, veniam aut fuga impedit sunt laboriosam praesentium ullam quisquam eos rem voluptas corporis vel hic natus!</p>

  <button class="show-dialog-btn">Show Dialog</button>
</div>


<!--- Locations 3 Div ---->
<div class="locations-container">
  <h2>Locations 3</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus aliquid quas, ut fugiat, ipsum, veniam aut fuga impedit sunt laboriosam praesentium ullam quisquam eos rem voluptas corporis vel hic natus!</p>

  <button class="show-dialog-btn">Show Dialog</button>
</div>


<!--- Dialog Box ---->
<div id="dialog-box">

  <h1>Dialog box</h1>
  <p>Dialog box text</p>
  <button class="close-dialog-btn">Close box </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use `position: fixed;` in the dialog-box css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `position: absolute` with `fixed` in `#dialog-box`:

```js
$('.show-dialog-btn').click(function() {

  $('#dialog-box').addClass('display-dialog-box');
  $('body').addClass('disable-scroll');
});



$('.close-dialog-btn').click(function() {

  $('#dialog-box').removeClass('display-dialog-box');
  $('body').removeClass('disable-scroll');
});
```

```css
.locations-container {
  padding: 10px
}

.locations-container:not(last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 100px
}

.locations-container:nth-child(3) {
  background: #eee
}

#dialog-box {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
  width: 220px;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)
}

#dialog-box.display-dialog-box {
  display: block
}

body.disable-scroll {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--- Locations 1 Div ---->
<div class="locations-container">
  <h2>Locations 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus aliquid quas, ut fugiat, ipsum, veniam aut fuga impedit sunt laboriosam praesentium ullam quisquam eos rem voluptas corporis vel hic natus!</p>

  <button class="show-dialog-btn">Show Dialog</button>
</div>


<!--- Locations 2 Div ---->
<div class="locations-container">
  <h2>Locations 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus aliquid quas, ut fugiat, ipsum, veniam aut fuga impedit sunt laboriosam praesentium ullam quisquam eos rem voluptas corporis vel hic natus!</p>

  <button class="show-dialog-btn">Show Dialog</button>
</div>


<!--- Locations 3 Div ---->
<div class="locations-container">
  <h2>Locations 3</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus aliquid quas, ut fugiat, ipsum, veniam aut fuga impedit sunt laboriosam praesentium ullam quisquam eos rem voluptas corporis vel hic natus!</p>

  <button class="show-dialog-btn">Show Dialog</button>
</div>


<!--- Dialog Box ---->
<div id="dialog-box">

  <h1>Dialog box</h1>
  <p>Dialog box text</p>
  <button class="close-dialog-btn">Close box </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You beat me to it! :thumbs-up:

Comment: Thank you, mates! Changing the position to "fixed" solved the problem of centering the box vertically at the scroll position. But is there a way to have the box stay in place once it's been centered and not scroll?

Comment: Updated answer: the body won't scroll once the modal being opened.